# Why is "животное" neuter even though it's animate?

Tags: род, одушевлённость

Russian differentiates between animate and inanimate nouns:

> Я вижу кот**а**
>
> Я вижу дом

In principle all animate nouns are either masculine or feminine but cannot be neuter. So why "животн**ое**" and not "животн**ая**" or "животн**ый**"?

Comment: Since the sex of said animal is not known, it makes total sense it to be neutral.

Comment: But still for some reason you do not wonder why [мертвец](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/мертвец#Noun) ('dead person') and [робот](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/робот#Noun_2) ('robot') are _masculine_ and _animate_. :D

Comment: @YellowSky the famous distinction between "мертвец" and "труп" ))) also - robots would like to have a word with you )))

Comment: A list of animate neuter nouns: http://gramdict.ru/search?symbol=со

Comment: Why people think that grammatical gender must coincide with biological sex of the living being? I think it is because in English nouns do not have gender and pronouns _he_ and _she_ (the only remnants of gender) are overwhelmingly used by this rule. (Although there is _child_ that can be substituted by _it_.) BUT in Russian (like in French) we use _he_ and _she_ in 99% of cases in accordance with gender of noun. For example, I will say _собака лаяла_ even though this individual dog was a male.

Comment: When you start learning German don’t wonder that a German girl is not feminine, she is neuter - *das Mädchen*.

Comment: @SergeySlepov. Cool site!

Comment: @shabunc actually this makes perfect sense to me. Мертвец refers to the dead person with his/her personality and identity, whereas труп refers to the dead body, the flesh of a being (not necessarily a human by the way, it can also be an animal). Consider the sentence: "кладя труп в могилу, все вспоминали мертвеца, как с ним общали и дружили." Switching труп and мертвец in this sentence would sound strange.

Comment: @Abakan Das weiß ich seit einer langen Zeit, danke ^^ By the way, there is an interesting parallel between Mädchen and девушка: Mädchen comes from "die Magd", today meaning a (female) servant, but back then it meant a girl. To that was added the diminutive ending "-schen", which make the word neuter (das Herrschen). In Russian девушка comes from дева + -ка, which is the same construction. -ка just happens to make words feminine (at least in the declination, sometimes they remain grammatically masculine - один мужчина) and not neuter, but if it did, дебушка would have been neuter ^^

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The real answer is **the claim** that "in principle all animate nouns are either masculine or feminine but cannot be neutral" **is false**. For instance, we consider obsolete yet existent word ["дитё"](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%91) (or "дитя") which is animate and neuter. Or "чадо", or "существо", or "чудовище" etc.

The situation is not unique to Russian, there's a famous example from German, a [Mädchen](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/M%C3%A4dchen) or [Kind](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Kind), which are also neuter.

Animacy and gender are different grammar features and while relationships between 
them are complicated. That complicated that some researchers even go that far that they conclude that there's [more than 3 genders](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grammatical_gender#Slavic_languages) in Russian and some other Slavic languages.

It's quite safe, however. to assume that animacy/inanimacy doesn't necessarily implies specific gender.

Here's [a quote](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Animacy#Animacy_as_a_%22subgender%22) from wikipedia:

> While animacy is viewed as primarily semantic when approached
>   diachronically, a synchronic view suggests animacy as a sublevel of
>   gender. Syntactic gender is defined through patterns in agreement, not
>   necessarily semantic value. For example, Russian has "common gender"
>   nouns that refer to traditionally masculine roles but act as
>   syntactically feminine.

Comment: This isn't **my claim** but one of my study book[1] ^^ However I took the time to check other sources and indeed, animate neuter nouns, however rare, do exist in Russian.

[1] Le Russe sans peine, Victoria Melnikova-Suchet, Assimil, 2008 (ISBN 978-2-7005-0382-1)

Comment: @almerillat - Oh!.. I've had a look at the book and it really says, "Neuter nouns are always inanimate, because animate nouns are always either feminine or masculine; the accusative is therefore the same as the nominative." (page 527 in my English-language 2011 edition). That is really wrong, as you can see Russian does have neuter gender animate nouns, and they have accusative same as the nominative _only in the singular_, in the plural they have accusative same as the _genitive_, like all the animate plural nouns.

Comment: @YellowSky yes exactly there, in the grammar section at the end of the book. Didn't know it hat been translated in English by the way.

Comment: @almerillat - Beside the [English version](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1f8i_b44TR3yc4SB0RcV83fVU92ozQ3ac/view?usp=sharing), I've also seen a Spanish one.